# OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I'm trying to setup a server from Mac terminal.

I've established a connection on port 5000 and want to open another port in `5002` using this command:

```
python Blockchain.py -p 5002
```

But this gives the error:

> OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

I tried to verify if port 5002 is open and listening. So I run
shell command `lsof -i:5002` but it returns none.

#### Stacktrace

Error log & stacktrace attached below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Blockchain.py", line 290, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 666, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/anaconda/envs/blockchain/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

#### Research

I've referred various answers on the same issue:

- [socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use/19071568)
- [Flask and Pycharm socket.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818572/flask-and-pycharm-socket-error)
- [Python - Socket Error, Address In Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765351/python-socket-error-address-in-use)

#### What I tried

Also, I tried the following methods to resolve the issue:

1. Restarting the terminals
2. Restarting PyCharm
3. Running on different sockets (gives same error).

None of that seems to work. I'm fairly new to Python.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

While trying to implement [answer suggested by DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51309985/5730279) I stumbled across the following answer:

[Python - How to run multiple flask apps from same client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205495/python-how-to-run-multiple-flask-apps-from-same-client-machine)

To run Flask application on different machines use:

```sh
export FLASK_APP=Blockchain.py
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

Next, open up another terminal and use:

```sh
export FLASK_APP=Blockchain.py
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001
```

Credits: user [metmirr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5802335/metmirr)

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the traceback you will see

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

which means that no matter what port is passed in by `-p`, port 5000 is hardcoded.

You will need to modify it to use whatever variable the script is storing the `-p` argument as.