# How to resolve persistent node error "EADDRINUSE"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, localhost

I'm trying to run an http server through node but I keep getting the `EADDRINUSE` error with specifically port 5000 (trying various others works fine). I have tried using `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` and `sudo kill -9 [PID]`. Here is one of those shell lines:

```
Borealis:BackEnd grepgrok$ sudo lsof -i tcp:5000
COMMAND     PID  USER       FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 34117  grepgrok   26u  IPv4 0x64883005c755e215      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 34117  grepgrok   27u  IPv6 0x64883005c59ef42d      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
Borealis:BackEnd grepgrok$ sudo kill -9 34117
Borealis:BackEnd grepgrok$
```

Yet I still get

```
Borealis:BackEnd grepgrok$ node ./bin/www
Port 5000 is already in use
```

Note: I am basing this off the `npx express-generator` sample project which includes this for errors:

```
function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `lsof -i :5000 -t | xargs kill`

Comment: @dealwap still didn't work

Comment: Why don´t you just change your Node.js http server configuration to a different port?

Comment: @DWA mostly for stylistic reasons, also, at this point I just REALLY want to know what is going on here.

Comment: Are you on OSx? Airplay is using this port: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829313/5781499

Comment: @Marc that was the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working (mostly except for a bit of funk) is using `kill-port 5000; nodemon app.js` as my `npm run dev` script.